# how to create a widget for an already created app in android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, widget

How to create a widget in the same program as the app?
As in how to create a widget for an app which does the same functions?

This is the activity file:

```
    public class SmsActivity extends Activity {
    Button b1;
    EditText a;
    String b;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    a=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e2);
    a.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
b=a.getText().toString();
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
    });
    b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try {
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, b);                 
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
} 
    catch (Exception e) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
"SMS failed, please try again later!",
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
e.printStackTrace();
}
    }
    });
}
    }
```

I don't want updation through widget. I just want the widget to do the exact same what the app does.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do input with a widget, so you can't have EditText fields. Widgets are output only.